# Doing BLE pairing and communication remotely

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried looking everywhere to understand how BLE pairing works but unable to find answers. Lets say I have a small device, like a raspberry pi with a BLE dongle. What I'd like to do is to allow BLE pairing and then subsequent communication with a BLE peripheral (such as a BLE temperature sensor) using software only.

My aim is to try and see if I can control the pairing and then getting the temperature, without touching the sensor at all, so that in future, I can just remotely log into the raspberry pi, turn on bluetooth, obtain the temperature reading and then afterwards turn it off again. And in future if I need to obtain the reading again, I'll repeat the process.

So:

1. Can this "simple" scenario be achieved using some software based control?
2. If not, then which parts require manual input and then which don't?

The BLE sensor should not be in advertisement mode or broadcasting the information. It should only send the data to paired devices.

Any and all answers appreciated! :-)

Comment: I'm not sure which part is making you think you can't do it...  As long as the BLE temperature sensor is on and is connectable then another device can connect to it.  The other device could be a Rpi with a BLE dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Most Bluetooth low energy devices do not require pairing at all so check first that your sensors do have this requirement. If they do then you need to determine which specific pairing procedure is required. Bluetooth defines various ways to authenticate during pairing and these generally relate to the I/O capabilities of the two devices and are called Association Models. In some cases, pairing "just works" (the name of the simplest association model) and no user interaction is required. In others, say if one device has a keyboard but the other has a display and no keyboard, the second device will display a random 6 digit number and the user must key that number into the first device. All of this is defined in the Bluetooth Core specification.

In your case the pairing procedure will be defined for your sesnors in the manufacturer documentation so check there first. Not that you should only have to do this once per device, not every time you want to read the sensor.

Accessing sensor data remotely needs a gateway which I guess is what your Pi will do. The Bluetooth SIG defined a set of RESTFul HTTP APIs for exactly this purpose. See https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/white-papers

The SIG also provides a gateway developer resource for Raspberry Pi which you can download including source code which is written in node.js. See https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/developer-resources-tools

Good luck